# Browser JS show trail of moving object in a video

Tags: javascript, html, image, image-processing

[Falling ball trail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giaJ0.png)

I'm trying to make a website that gets frames from a video and merges into a single photo like the image above.

I currently succeeded in loading the video and extracting the frames.
The only thing left is merging the frames into one, and I tried that with a canvas.

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'darken';
ctx.drawImage(frame, 0, 0, w, h);
```

[Moving ball trail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5KTm.png)

But the ball's top half is hard to see because of the dark background.
I also tried other composition operations, but I couldn't find anything nice.

Is there a nice way to make a object's trail from multiple pictures?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.